# Backup solution for home network

Tags: debian, ubuntu, windows

I have been looking into some solutions regarding backing up all data from clients that are connected within our home network to a remote location for safe keeping.
I figured that if I could get data stored on local linux distributions and windows automatically moved to the server that we have running here I could take advantage of the "crashplan" plan for 1 computer to backup all PC's within my home network.

My question is, what would be a good solution to automatically, reliably and consistently move files from the computers within the home network to my server so my server can then upload these files to crashplan?

Comment: What's the OS of "the server"?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that the server runs the server version of debian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look through the list of backup software at https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#backups; for Linux clients, I've had good luck with `rsync` (just mirror) or `rsnapshot` (deltas over time via hard link tree, but probably overkill if you just want a simple `rsync` mirror for crashplan to work on); on the Windows side I've less experience, though perhaps a Samba share and robocopy might do the trick?